# PHP string inside do_something-tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to perform this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[add_to_cart item="<?php the_field('item_number'); ?>"]'); ?>
```

How do I add the_field-tag inside the do_shortcode-tag?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *get the field* within the loop I guess, have you tried that?

```
 <?php $theField = get_field('item_number'); ?>
```

Then echo your shortcode

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode('[add_to_cart item="'.$theField.'"]'); ?>
```

Comment: That works great. This solution will help me on another projet as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Do:

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode('[add_to_cart item="' . the_field('item_number') . '"]'); ?>
```

You never can put a php tag inside another php tag. The code would break.

Comment: That's correct but I've tried that already. I've found out that the problem is that the <?php the_field('item_number'); ?> adds several blank spaces. If the item_number is for example 12. The output is "    12  ". Is there a way to remove that extra blank space from the the_field tag?